# Can two different definitions of acidity and basicity be used together?

Tags: acid-base

I wanted to predict the pH of $\ce{PH3}$, it has basic nature as it has a lone pair of electrons. But it also has acidic nature as its $\ce{P-H}$ bonds are weak. Now according to the  Lewis definition $\ce{PH3}$ is a base and according to Bronsted-Lowry definition it is a acid. Can we say from this that $\ce{PH3}$ is neutral?

Comment: Nope, you definitely can't say that PH3 is neutral. It depends on the case- PH3 will react like a Bronsted Lowry acid with Bronsted Lowry base, and it will react like a Lewis base with a Lewis acid.

Comment: A rather weak base and an awfully weak acid, I must say.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.  And by convention, after the full stop/period at the end of a phrase, we use a space.

Answer (score 5):

Put simple: these are two *mutually independent* definitions.

- The Bronsted concept is based on the possibility to donate a proton (i.e., an acid), or to accept a proton (i.e., a base).  But it isn't only the presence/absence of a proton in a compound, it equally depends on the reaction partner if a molecule may act as an acid, or as a base.
- The Lewis concept is based on the presence of an non-bonded electron pair (Lewis base), or empty molecule orbital (Lewis acid).

Since the two concepts take a different perspective, which is independent of each other, it is possible (but not a requirement) that the two concepts independently assign a compound to be an acid, or a base.  It happens e.g., the hydroxide $\ce{OH-}$ anion indeed simultaneously is both a Bronsted base as well as a Lewis base.  But since the two concepts are set up independently of each other, you can't «neutralize» acidity assigned by one theory with basicity assigned by the other theory.